# Why does Modal open a new open pop up?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

Noticing a strange behaviour which I cannot understand when I am trying to open a modal using `ng-bootstrap`

```
 openModal(content,modalActionType) {
        this.modalActionType = modalActionType;
        console.log(this.modalActionType);
        open(content);
        return false;
  }
  open(content) {
        this.modalService.open(content, {ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title'})
        .result.then((saveOrCancel) => {
        }, (dismissReason) => {});
   }
```

HTML

```
<a class="dropdown-item" (click)="openModal(content,'Reset')">Reset Password</a>
```

When I click on Reset Password a new tab is opened up inspite of me returning false from the `openModal` function.

Strangely the code below works and the **Modal opens up as expected**. Why does this happen ?

```
openModal(content,modalActionType) {
    this.modalActionType = modalActionType;
    console.log(this.modalActionType);
    this.modalService.open(content, {ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title'})
    .result.then((saveOrCancel) => {
    }, (dismissReason) => {});
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: open(content); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `openModal` method:

```
openModal(content,modalActionType) {
    this.modalActionType = modalActionType;
    console.log(this.modalActionType);
    open(content);
    return false;
}
```

The third line of the method `open(content);` should be changed to `this.open(content);` to ensure it calls the `open` method you defined in your component TypeScript file rather than `window.open()` - which will open a new window or tab (depending on the browser).

Please see [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-icuwkm?file=app%2Fmodal-basic.ts) for a demo. If you change line 18 in `modal-basic.ts` from `this.open(content);` to `open(content);` it will open a new browser tab rather than opening the modal.